# Glitches / Artifacts appear when animating model

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

I have this character that I need to animate for a major project but I get these errors as I move around the bones. Wondering why this is happening and if there is a fix. Thanks[image]

Comment: The mesh looks very dense because of these artifacts. Is this a sculpted character model? How have you weight-painted it?

Comment: Yes, it is sculpted and is a quite dense model. though it has far fewer vertices than it once had because of another error. Most bones in the model are paired via automatic weights.

Comment: Have you considered a [retopology](https://youtu.be/S4YNiImIgPs)? A low-poly mesh gives you better performance and deformation, and it's easier to texture and weight-paint.

Comment: This look like your bone weights are going abruptly from 1 to 0 so the vertices are sheared at the interface